# Insert data into an HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML table with 5 rows and 5 columns (table.html). I need to insert letter 'A' on each cell. How do I achieve this using javascript?

Comment: can you post your code, if you have tried??

Comment: `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "Some text to enter";`. Post you full code if there is still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only JavaScript (no jQuery):

JavaScript

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
    var cell = cells[i];
    cell.innerText = "A " + cell.innerText;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/8tfhvao5/1/)

**EDIT**

If you want to target a specific table, you can do this by setting an id on it and using something like this:

```
var cells = document.getElementById("a-table").getElementsByTagName("td");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/8tfhvao5/2/)

Comment: thanks for the solution. However the htm and javascript are separate files. Isn't there like a reference to point out to the HTML on the javascript code or the other way around?

Comment: Either you need to include the code in a <script> tag, or reference it, also with a script tag <script src="locationOfScript">. You probably want to add `window.onload = function () { //Code here }` around the code also, to await the execution until page loads.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arg0n. I tried with <script src...>. It worked

Answer (score 1):

If you are usin jQuery. It is very simple

```
$('td').each(function(){
   $(this).html('A' + $(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Simpler:  `$('td').prepend('A ')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using the selector that suits you, for example:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("#table_id td"), function(el){
    el.innerHTML = 'A';
});
```